# Extracting numeric value from UItextfield post-NSFormatter decimal conversion

Tags: objective-c

I am having the user enter into a textfield a number, say 900000.  It is then formatted for decimal and shows on the screen as 900,000.  When I try to extract the numeric value from the formatted textfield, the number returned is 900.  Suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried String format specifiers? https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html

Answer (score 1):

You could prior to converting to a number delete the , with

`stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@""`

But this will not work in much of the world where a ' is used as the decimal point.

Better to use an NSNumberFormatter:

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [NSNumberFormatter new];
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle;
NSNumber *numberObject = [numberFormatter numberFromString:@"900,000"];
NSLog(@"numberObject: %@", numberObject);
int numberInt = [numberObject intValue];
NSLog(@"numberInt: %d", numberInt);
```

Output:

> numberObject: 900000
>   numberInt: 900000

Answer (score 0):

have you tried removing the comma?

```
str = [str stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@","
                                     withString:@""];

int value = [str intValue];
```